How to calculate $\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{ln}(ax^2+bx +c) dx$?
In $\ $Matthew D. Schwartzs Quantum Field Theory$\ $ book, p. $302$, he derives next formula
$$
{\rm i}\,\mathcal{M}_{\rm loop}(p) =
-\,{\rm i}\,\frac{g^{2}}{32 \pi^{2}}
\int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}x\ \ln\left(\frac{m^{2} - p^{2}x\left[1-x\right]}{\Lambda^{2}}\right) \tag{16.10}
$$
and he asserts that this integral can be done ( the integrand is perfectly well behaved between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ ) and for $m = 0$ it has the simple form
$$
\mathcal{M}_{\rm loop}\left(p\right) =
\frac{g^{2}}{32\pi^{2}}
\left[2 - \ln\left(-\,\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda^{2}}\right)\right]. \tag{16.11}
$$

How can we prove this derivation ?.
Perhaps, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}x\ 
\ln\left(x - x^{2}\right) = -2$ ? or in general,
$$
\mbox{how can we calculate}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}
\ln\left(ax^{2} + bx + c\right){\rm d}x\ ?.$$
If the definite integral is true, then by setting $m = 0$ in $\left(16.10\right)$ we can derive the $\left(16.11\right)$.

Can any one help ?.

$\int\ln(ax^2+bx+c),\mathrm{d}x = \int1\cdot\ln(ax^2+bx+c),\mathrm{d}x$, integrate by parts

@RaadShaikh : O.K. Thanks.

We have,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1 \ln(x - x^2) \ \mathrm{d}x & = \int_{0}^1 [\ln(x) + \ln(1-x)] \ \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{0}^1 \ln(x) \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^1 \ln(1-x) \ \mathrm{d}x \\
& = 2 \int_{0}^1 \ln(x) \ \mathrm{d}x  \\
& = 2 \bigg[ x \ln x - x \bigg]_0^1 \\
& = -2.
\end{align*}
For the lower bound, you actually take the limit $x \to 0^{+}$.
For the general case, rewrite $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln(ax^2 + bx + c) \ \mathrm{d}x$ as $\displaystyle \int_0^1 [\ln(a) + \ln(x - \alpha) + \ln(x- \beta)] \ \mathrm{d}x$ and then separately solve all the integrals. Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic equation.

Brilliant! Thank you for answer ~( You teach me a kind of technique for integrating seemingly somewhat complicated function by division~ )
